# Yii framework and widgets aliases (YiiWheels)

Tags: php, yii, widget

I am using Yii version (1.1.14) and I want to use some uf yiwheels features and plugins in my application. I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xeskc6pph0

and tried to set up everithing according to steps in this tutorial. 
But datepicker which I am trying to use cannot be found by Yii. What am I doing wrong, or is something missing?

**config/main.php:**

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'My Web Application',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload' => array('log'),
    //path aliases
    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'),
        'yiiwheels' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/yiiwheels'),
    ),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
        'bootstrap.helpers.TbArray',
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii' => array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => 'Enter Your Password Here',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', '::1'),
        ),
    ),
    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'user' => array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',
        ),
        'yiiwheels' => array(
            'class' => 'yiiwheels.YiiWheels',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

          'urlManager'=>array(
          'urlFormat'=>'path',
          'rules'=>array(
          '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
          ),
          ),

        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        /*
          'db'=>array(
          'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
          'emulatePrepare' => true,
          'username' => 'root',
          'password' => '',
          'charset' => 'utf8',
          ),
         */
        'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
        'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning',
                ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
              array(
              'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
              ),
             */
            ),
        ),
    ),
    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params' => array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

**views/layouts/main.php:**

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

        <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/form.css" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>

<div class="container" id="page">

    <div class="input-append">
                    <?php                  
                    $this->widget('yiwheels.widgets.datepicker.WhDatePicker', array (
                        'name' => 'datepickertest',
                        'pluginoptions' => array(
                            'format' => 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                        )
                    ));                 
                    ?>           
     </div>

.....
```

I have following error:

Alias "yiwheels.widgets.datepicker.WhDatePicker" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a typo:

```
$this->widget('yiwheels.
```

Change to:

```
$this->widget('yiiwheels.
```

Or you need to change your alias in the config to this:

```
'yiwheels' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/yiiwheels'),
```

Comment: Oh, yes, now it works, thank you very much, such embarrassing mistake :).

Comment: No problem, something every single developer has done many many times.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

You try to use alias : `yiwheels` but your alias is defined `yiiwheels`